# Aliasing connected actions renders them invisible in an IDE

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, redux, react-redux, eslint

I want to connect / bind actions in the same file in which I am defining my component, and ideally would like this component to be functional. The problem is doing this means I must alias my action so as to avoid the eslint rule [no-shadow](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow). You can see this in the code block below. However, I also use an IDE and aliasing these actions renders them invisible to my IDE when trying to find all usages of said actions.

Is there a way I can connect these dispatched actions to my functional component while making said actions visible to my IDE for debugging?

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {actionOne, actionTwo}  from '../../../../actions';

const ComponentOne = ({actionOneDispatch, actionTwoDispatch}) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    actionOneDispatch();
    actionTwoDispatch()
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  actionOneDispatch: () => {
    dispatch(actionOne());
  },
  actionTwoDispatch: () => {
    dispatch(actionTwo());
  },
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentOne);
```

Comment: Actually the usage of your actions is in `mapDispatchToProps` because that is where they are called. If your IDE shows the usage in the component itself that would be wrong because there only the function that dispatches them is used and not the action itself. If you keep `mapDispatchToProps` close to your component you can still easily find it's usage.